# How can I align the text according to this picture?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular8

I have been trying to align the text accordingly through bootstrap and I am not able to do so

What I want to do:
[image: What I want the image to be]

What I have been able to do so far:
[image: What I am able to do]

my code:

````
      <!-- <app-dr-peter></app-dr-peter> -->
      <div style="text-align: center">
        <h1>Dr. Peters</h1>
      </div>
      <div style="text-align: center">
        <h2>Estimated Wait Time <u>{{ waitTimePeter }} min.</u></h2>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div *ngFor="let ptr of DrPtrData; let i = index">
        <h3 class="d-lg-inline-block">{{ i+1 }}. {{ ptr.name }}</h3>
        <h3 class="d-lg-inline-block">{{ ptr.eta }}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `d-lg-inline-block`, you can try using bootstraps flexbox utilities such as `d-flex`, on the containing div. Here's an example :

```
<div *ngFor="let ptr of DrPtrData; let i = index" class="d-flex justify-content-between">
  <h3>{{ i+1 }}. {{ ptr.name }}</h3>
  <h3>{{ ptr.eta }}</h3>
</div>
```

To reduce the space between the two columns, you can wrap it in a container with a fixed width:

```
<div style="width: 400px">
   ... [your list goes here]
</div>
```

This is only an example, preferably you should use a css class for the fixed width.

Comment: How would I be able to reduce the space in between the two headings?

Comment: You could wrap it in a container with a fixed width. I've added an example to the answer. If you have more specific requirements, it would be helpful if you added them to your question, because as it stands, it isn't really clear what you want from it.